# Need to manually 'browse' in IIS in order to start .net core service

Tags: iis, .net-core

I have a service written in .net core that I am hosting in IIS. Unless I click on 'browse', the logs don't get generated(I think the service doesn't get called unless I manually click).

I feel the issue is with launchSettings.json.

Below is the same :

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:57346",
      "sslPort": 44395
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "values",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Services.NotificationHub": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "values",
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I modify the same here to tell IIS to run the service without me having to manually click on 'browse'.

Comment: How did you host your application? In-process or out-of-process? If that's in-process. You could try to set your application pool to always running and enable preload.https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/

Comment: IIS doesn't read your launchSettings.json file, and it only runs your .NET Core application when the first request comes by default. Some might claim that you can let your .NET Core app always running, https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html#making-asp-net-core-application-always-running-on-iis But that never is the recommended approach.

Comment: @Jokies Ding - Its in-process and I did try setting the application pool to always running and enable preload. Still no luck.

Comment: @LexLi tI need to keep .NET core app always running. It's a service that listens to webSocket and redirects messages to clients. I did try setting app pool to alwaysRunning and idle timeout etc. No luck..